# Get Childrens name in Multi Node Tree Picker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

I've trying to get the names of some pages, chosen with a Multinode Tree Picker in Umbraco
The version im using is Umbraco 7.01, and MVC

The scenario is: I have a newspage, on this page I can select some categories with a Multinode Tree Picker, The items im choosing is Pages. 
Right now, im getting the ID's from the pages, but I cant it loop the ID's and return the page name ??? However, it seems it never gets in the second foreach() loop

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
var getCategories = CurrentPage.category.Split(','); //My Picker, This can be several pages = more ID om pages, that why the split

<p>@CurrentPage.category//This returns 1077,1079</p> 

@foreach (string id in getCategories)
{
    @id //This return 1077 1079
    foreach (var catItem in Umbraco.TypedContent(id).Children)
    {
        <p>@catItem.Name</p>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nicky,

I have seen this before I am sure of it.  Anyhow can you try

```
var getCategories = CurrentPage.category.Split(',').ToList();
```

Regards

Ismail

Comment: Then I get the error: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'

Comment: Add using for system.linq

Answer (score 0):

Nicky,

OK different track, try the following via strongly typed access which is prefered way of doing this in mvc umbraco:

```
var getCategories = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("category").Split(',').ToList();
```

Regards

Ismail

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@foreach (string id in getCategories)
{
    @id //This return 1077 1079
    foreach (var catItem in Umbraco.TypedContent(id).Children)
    {
        <p>@catItem.Name</p>
    }
}
```

To something like:

```
@foreach (string id in getCategories)
{
@id //This return 1077 1079
int nodeId = -1;
Int32.TryParse(id,out nodeId);
Node x = new Node(nodeId);
foreach (var catItem in x.Children)
{
<p>@catItem.Name</p>
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know about nicky, but in Umbraco 7.1.4, I get the following error: "The type or namespace name 'Node' could not be found..."

Comment: You should add following reference to your view 

@using umbraco.NodeFactory